# Operator norm of a matrix, geometric series of which is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have a series of matrices $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}M^{n}$ which is convergent, where $M \in R^{N \times N}$. Is it true that the operator norm of M, $||M||_{2}$, must be smaller than 1?

I tried taking the operator norm of the series, but could only upper bound it using triangle inequality, which doesn't have to converge. I tried to use the fact that the operator norm of M is the largest singular value, but still couldn't prove.

Comment: The answer is no. For any nilpotent matrix the series reduces to a finite sum. In general if the series is convergent, the absolute value of all eigenvalues should be strictly less than $1.$ Your first claim is correct for normal matrices.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. As a simple counterexample, take
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&2\\0&0}.
$$
We have $\|M\|_2 = 2 > 1$, but
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}M^{n} = I + M + 0 + 0 + \cdots = \pmatrix{1&2\\0&1}.
$$